# yii-user registration form as popup using ajax in yii

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii, yii-extensions

am using yii-user extension for registration. it works perfect .but my reqiurement is to render the registration form using ajax on pages with menu ,which contains this register as menuitem .i dont want is user to be redirected to some other page. 
my need is on whichever page she may be she can register from their via ajax registration form on that particular page

```
  array('url'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->registrationUrl, 'label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Register"), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
```

this wrks and redirects me to user/registration page but my need is ajax popup up on any page when register item is clicked.

i did something like
and in script

```
    function showmod()
{




 document.getElementById("showdata").style.display = "block";


 //alert("hi1");

 //  alert("hi");
    var xmlhttp;    

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
         {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
      else
     {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
    // alert("hi2");
    document.getElementById("showdata").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

//alert("h2");
  }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo Yii::app()->getModule('user')->registrationUrl ;?>",true);

    //alert("h1");


   xmlhttp.send();

    }

  array( 'url'=>'#','label'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Register"), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest,array('click'=>"showmod()")),
```

doesnt work

a similar post i have posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164620/yii-user-registration-view-in-model-window

as its been extracted in module folder .might be thats error i dont what is it please let me know

can anyone please help ,guide,suggest how do achieve so

Comment: for the link you have mentioned, clearly it will not work because you are writing a php statment in javascript. You need to write <?php echo Yii::app()->getModule('user')->registrationUrl ;?>

Comment: sorry for delay to reposne had done the same thing know hv updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here instead of

```
          xmlhttp .open("GET","<?php echo Yii::app()->getModule('user')->registrationUrl ;?>",true);
```

this wrks

```
    xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/index.php/user/registration",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap inbuilt css files we can do popus..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#opn').trigger("click");
        $('#myModal').on('hide', function (e) {
        window.location.href = "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('product/admin'); ?>"
           });


        });</script>


<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="opn" style="margin-top: 30%; display:none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade product" style="width:1000px; id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
///your form

</div>
```

modal fade is inbuilt CSS CLASS  if you are using bootstrap..